# Ingenico Device - Disable all receipts print on MOVE5000

Tags: python, payment

I'm using a python library to manipulate Ingenico mobile payment device through RS232/USB connection. I'm developing an integration from my own POS solution. I would like to know of i can turn off receipts ( disable both customer and marchand receipts) on a Ingenico Move 5000 terminal. Currently i can only put customer receipt printing to OPTIONAL (asked to the client) but i didn't found how to disable the marchant receipt.

Thanks for help.

For older device (ICT250), i read that we can disable all receipts from an admin menu (put RcptCopies to 1 disable all receipts) but i can't found on MOVE5000 device how to access to the admin menu and the RcptCopies param.